# iptables rules for FTP

Tags: iptables, ftp

I've seen a few examples online... but what rules do you guys use in live environments to control your FTP usage?  Basic usage, nothing special, but I hear I need to be able to support active ftp sessions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a basic setup:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Also need to tell iptables to load the kernel module that tracks FTP connections in /etc/sysconfig/iptables-config:

```
IPTABLES_MODULES="ip_conntrack_ftp"
```

Comment: where would I add the IPTABLES_MODULES part ?  To my rules file?

Comment: No, it goes in /etc/sysconfig/iptables-config file

Comment: I don't have an iptables-config file anywhere.  I'm running ubuntu